# How to solve a recurrence

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Apologies for this is a really trivial question, but I cannot figure out what to do after understanding the pattern of the function.

Say I have this:

$\begin{align}
T(n) & = T(n-1) + 1/n \\
& = T(n-2) + 1/(n-1) + 1/n \\
& = T(n-3) + 1/(n-2) + 1/(n-1) + 1/n \\
\end{align}$

So after back-substituting a few times, at the $k$th step, I get this:

$T(n) = T(n-k) + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 1/(n-i)$

Now what do I do? How would I arrive at a $\theta$ answer from that equation?

Comment: what about choosing $k= n-1$?

Comment: @JonasGomes I really have zero idea about my next steps, so no matter how idiotic it is, can you clarify why I need to choose a k/why it's n-1/what I need to do with it?

Comment: If you want to compute $T(n)$ for every $n$, then probably you have $T(1)$, right? So, when we choose $k=n-1$ we have $T(n) = T(1) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 1/(n-i)$ wich is almost a closed formula

Answer (score 0):

$$T(k)-T(k-1)=\frac{1}{k} \implies \sum^{n}_{k=1}(T(k)-T(k-1))=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$ so this is a telescoping sum , solving it we get $$T(n)-T(0)=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$ thus $$T(n)=T(0)+\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: The last summation is just $H_n$, the harmonic number.